# Coming up with single filter function for both querysets and objects

Tags: django

I have a Django 1.10 project. Let's say I have a model like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, ...)
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager()

    class QuerySet(QuerySet):
       def university_rating(self, level): 
          return self.filter(university__rating = level)

class University(models.Model):
    rating = IntegerField(...)
```

So, if we want to filter students by their university rating, we hide model logic from the view code by using `Student.objects.univesity_rating(5)` instead of `Student.objects.filter(university__rating = level`. This approach is very DRY in that if I decide to change my model structure so that it affects the way we filter students by their university rating, we will have to make amendments in one place only, instead of tearing hair on our heads replacing snippets across the whole project.

But!

This code above works only for `QUERYSETS`, and does not work for `MODELS INSTANCES`. That is, let's say that (no matter how innatural that is, just let's imagine that as illustrative example), student surname and his university level uniquely defines the student - if there is such student.

So I want to do something like:

```
try:
    student = Stundent.objects.get(surname = ..., university__rating = level)
except Student.DoesNotExist:
    ...
```

The problem is that my custom filter did not help me in this case, and I had no way out but to explicitly write `university__rating` phrase in my view code. Is there any elegant way to come up with a Django structure that would enable filtering for both instances and querysets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.get` on querysets, so:

```
try:
    student = Stundent.objects.univesity_rating(level).get(surname = ...)
except Student.DoesNotExist:
    ...
```

Comment: I think, no better solution exists )

Comment: Simple and effective. Didn't think about it. Thanks much